# Embedded linux machine shutdowns itself

Tags: linux, shutdown, embedded

I have a tablet computer with some preconfigured embedded Linux onboard. There’s a strange problem I cannot get over: This tablet automatically shuts itself down within 60 seconds after it starts.

The startup procedure seems quite normal: `inittab` launches `/etc/init.d/rcS` which executes a number of scripts from `/etc/init.d` folder, after that I am able to log in via serial connection.

I certainly doesn’t overheat and unlikely have hardware problem, it just shutdowns itself after 60 seconds exactly. I believe this is done programmatically.

What can possibly cause such behavior? Is it possible to fix this without documentation or contact with developers?

Comment: Try a web search for "intercept linux shutdown" for ideas to try.

Comment: logs would help, depending on how your embedded linux logs. A *lot* more details on what this machine is would help

Comment: *"A lot more details ..."* -- A `ls -l /etc/init.d` could reveal if this system is using SysV or Busybox initialization.  Filenames with Snn... and Knn... indicate a Busybox init.   A `cat /etc/inittab` is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It was a custom IGEP board and something was encoded in the firmware to stop it if some kind of serial number does not match. Our partners sent updated firmware and problem was solved.